# Visual Studio Search Issue

Tags: regex, search, ide, visual-studio-2005

I have a problem in VS2005. When I try to search files with the regular expressions option  I just get an error message stating

```
Unknown argument for ':' operator. Complete Regular Expression required in search string.
```

The pattern that i'm trying to use is valid, and works in other text editors it is:

```
<asp:textbox.+?(type="text"|size=|autocomplete=|class=|value=)
```

How do I get this pattern working with VS2005 search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working :

```
\<asp\:textbox.+?(type=\"text\"|size=|autocomplete=|class=|value=)
```

But I think there is a mistake in **.+?** part. Wtihout it I can get matches for that :

```
// <asp:textboxtype="text"
```

Comment: The question mark is there to hint the ".+" to not be too greedy. But you are correct after escaping those characters and removing the question mark it seems to work fine, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try:
`< asp\:textbox.+?(type="text"|size=|autocomplete=|class=|value=)`

(blank between less-than and "asp" added to appease wmd editor. It shouldn't be there)

Answer (score 0):

The specific cause of your error is that visual studio regular expression searching uses : to indicate character types, and :te isn't a character property.  Escaping the : with a \ will cause it to be read as a :.